# Showing a convex inequality for closed intervals

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

Let $q:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. In my notes we showed the following inequalities:

$$q(y)\geq q(x)+q'_+(x)(y-x)$$

$$q(y)\geq q(x)+q'_-(x)(y-x)$$

for all $x,y \in (a,b)$, where $q'_+$ and $q'_-$ denote the right and left derivatives respectively (they exist because of convexity).

**Question:** Suppose now $q:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a convex function on a compact interval $[a,b]$. Can I find a function $f$ such that

$$q(y)\geq q(x)+f(x)(y-x)$$

for all $x,y \in [a,b]$?

Looking the proof, I believe the two inequalities still hold for $x\in (a,b)$ and $y\in[a,b]$, i.e. the same argument goes through. At $x=a$ we might have $q'_+(a)=-\infty$ however.

Comment: Think about $q(x) = -\sqrt x$ on $[0,1]$ at $x = 0$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith In this case $q(0)=0$, $q'_+(0)=-\infty$ and $q(y)\geq g(0)+q'_+(0)(y-0)$ for $y\in[0,1]$ (using the convention $-\infty \cdot 0=0$). So it seems like the first inequality still holds at $0$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Hence if I let $f(x)=q'_+(x)$ if $x\in[a,b)$ and $f(x)=q'_-(x)$ if $x=b$ would it be ok?

Comment: I thought that you wanted to avoid infinity.  But if that is not a problem for you, then your solution is fine.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith How would you proceed otherwise? How can I avoid infinity?

Comment: The example I gave shows that you can't avoid infinity.